# Will aliasing the Quantity and UnitConvert functions to "in" and "to" create problems?

Tags: units, conversion

It seems that there is a lot of interest in enhancing the use of units in Mathematica; various solutions in the name of brevity, correctness, and general utility have been demonstrated. I've begun treating unit conversions in a very simple manner as listed below. My question: what problems might I run into making conversions in this manner? (It saves a little typing and seems somewhat easier to read to me, at the expense of defining "in" and "to" aliases.) (Mathematica v.9.0.1.0)

```
in = Quantity; to = UnitConvert;

Express x "in" feet:  

x = 100.0~in~"Feet"

100. ft

Convert "to" yards:

x~to~"Yards"

33.3333 yd

Convert to SI units:

x // to

30.48 m

"One stop shop" conversion:

x = 1.0~in~"kg"~to~"lb"

2.20462 lb
```

Comment: If you really want to use this kind of syntax it would be easier to convert things using Google, IMO... Try [this](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=100+yards+in+fetts&oq=100+yards+in+fetts&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.4985j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=100+feet+in+yards&oq=100+feet+in+yards&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i8i30l3.35828.41051.1.41195.23.20.3.0.0.2.525.6188.0j1j5j10j2j1.19.0...0.0.0..1c.1.16.psy-ab.3Aads9o4siY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.dmg&fp=cd12338db8422c0b&biw=1280&bih=739).

Comment: Seems fine to me